# how to send props from a Component to Redux FieldArray

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am using redux-form with an FieldArray and I need access to props in FieldArray component. I tried to pass props as following but I am getting error as "Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined"

```
<FieldArray name="docList" component={docs} props={this.props}/>

const docs= ({props, meta: {error, submitFailed}}) => {
    const {fields} = props;
    return (
    {fields.map((doc, index) => (
     <div>
            <Field component={CustomCom} name={`${doc}.size`} label="size"
                handleChange={(label, type) => this.customMethod(label, SIZE)}
                placeholder="" value={props.sizeValue}/>
     </div>
))}
```

Please let me know how can I pass and use props in FieldArray component. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your function parameters like this

`const docs= ({meta: {error, submitFailed}, ...props})`, or,

`const docs= ({fields, meta: {error, submitFailed}})`

FieldArray props would be added in the props object of the `docs` component, `redux-form` will maintain `fields` and `meta` object items by itself, rest props you pass in `FieldArray` will be appended to the `props` sent to `docs` component.

As an example

```
const renderMembers = props => {
  console.log(props);
  const {
    fields,
    meta: { touched, error, submitFailed }
  } = props;
  return (
    <ul>
      {fields.map((member, index) => (
        <li key={index}>foo</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
<FieldArray
  name="members"
  component={renderMembers}
  explicitProp={"Hello"}
/>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Brijesh :) I used ...props and it worked like a charm. I also wanted to check how can I use FieldArray with component which can have other methods too. Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63113844/how-to-use-fieldarray-with-a-component-which-can-have-other-functions . Everywhere functional component is being used on net. Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thank you.